# Bluestacks Uinput with Tincore

Tags: bluestacks, uinput

I'm using Bluestacks and tincore does not recognize my mouse as a pointer as I do not have UINPUTS.  Anyway I can add UINPUTS module to bluestacks?

Context is that I am trying to use tincore in bluestacks and have my mouse show up as a pointer.  Right now tincore is requiring uinput.  Is there a work around?  Do I need to install mouse drivers in bluestacks?

Comment: Please provide more information and context abaout your problem.

Comment: Context is that I am trying to use tincore in bluestacks and have my mouse show up as a pointer.  Right now tincore is requiring uinput.  Is there a work around?  Do I need to install mouse drivers in bluestacks?